# Systemd: how to keep the timer active after reboot?

Tags: systemd, coreos

I need to setup daily reboot of CoreOS machine. So I have `/etc/systemd/system/reboot.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily reboot

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c 'reboot'
```

...and `/etc/systemd/system/reboot.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily reboot

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 21:20:00
```

If I activate timer by `sudo systemctl start reboot.timer`, I see it in the list:

```
core@node-011 ~ $ sudo systemctl list-timers --all | grep reboot
Fri 2019-03-22 21:20:00 UTC  12h left  n/a                          n/a      reboot.timer                 reboot.service
core@node-011 ~ $
```

But after reboot this timer became turned off (not in the list).

How to configure it persistent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You activate SystemD units permanently with `enable`:

```
sudo systemctl enable reboot.timer
```

Note: `start` only starts them one time, and `enable` don't start them right away (only at next boot). You can combine both with the `--now` option:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now reboot.timer
```

will permanently activate the unit and starts it immediately.